# Creating custom kubernetes cli

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have some workflows where I would like to automate kubectl with some custom golang code.

Like Istio and others are using kubectl underneath istiocli.

Do I need all the Kubernetes code and import some stuff or is it calling existig kubectl in a shell with os/exec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing golang code, I would recommend you using [kubernetes client-go package](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) to automate the workflow. The only thing you need to be careful is that the client version keeps changing and if it's not consistent with your kubernetes cluster api-server version, you will need to change your client package version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [istio](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/istioctl/cmd/istioctl/main.go#L38) is using the k8s API client library:

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go

I would expect that to perform better and allow you to provide a better experience to your users than shelling out through `os/exec` and `exec.Command`.  It also won't require you reverse engineer or otherwise spend a bunch of cycles parsing the output from the commands.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way would be to create [a kubectl plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubectl/kubectl-plugins/).

> this feature allows you to extend the default set of commands
>   available in kubectl by adding new subcommands to perform new tasks
>   and extend the set of features available in the main distribution of
>   kubectl.
>
> [...] You can write a plugin in any programming language or script that
>   allows you to write command-line commands. A plugin does not
>   necessarily need to have a binary component. It could rely entirely on
>   operating system utilities like echo, sed, or grep. Or it could rely
>   on the kubectl binary.

[This repository](https://github.com/jordanwilson230/kubectl-plugins) contains some examples.